# Blueprints - qual o conceito? para que serve?

Tags: python, flask

Como dei meu voto para o Flask(python), vejo agora tantos exemplos utilizando blueprints. O que são? Para que servem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420857/what-are-flask-blueprints-exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os Blueprints, em minha humilde opinião, têm um nome muito ruim. Se fossem chamados "areas" ou "sections" ou "subsites" ninguém ficaria coçando a cabeça para tentar entender.

Na verdade Blueprints são muito simples e úteis principalmente para organizar sua app quando ela começa a ficar muito grande.

Você utiliza blueprints para separar as partes (seções) do seu site, como namespaces. Com as partes separadas, você pode fazer coisas como adicionar `before_request` callbacks apenas em blueprints específicos, *error handlers* específicos, separar os templates e/ou arquivos estáticos de cada blueprint em diretórios diferentes, criar globais ou filtros para as templates, etc.

Em suma, é até difícil você manter uma app grande sem usar blueprints e não enlouquecer.